# HQL Update cell value

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am going to update `password` of a user:

Here is my query:

```
@Transactional
public void resetPassInDB(String userEmail, String newPass) {

    Query query = userDao.getSession().createQuery("update User u set u.password = :password where u.email = :email");
    query.setParameter("password", newPass);
    query.setParameter("email", userEmail);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();    // is 0
}
```

But nothing changes!

**update**

This not worked too:

```
Query query = userDao.getSession().createQuery("from User where email= :email");
query.setParameter("email", userEmail);

User user = (User) query.list().get(0);
user.setPassword(newPass);
userDao.getSession().update(user);
```

In console:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.email as email2_2_, user0_.password as password3_2_, user0_.username as username4_2_ from User user0_ where user0_.email=?
```

**UPDATE2**

```
@Transactional
public void resetPassInDB(String userEmail, String newPass) {
    Query query = userDao.getSession().createQuery("from User where email= :email");
    query.setParameter("email", userEmail);

    User user = (User) query.list().get(0);
    System.out.println("retrieved user: " + user);
    user.setPassword(newPass);

    userDao.getSession().update(user);
    System.out.println("updated user: " + user);
}
```

Console:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.email as email2_2_, user0_.password as password3_2_, user0_.username as username4_2_ from User user0_ where user0_.email=?
retrieved user: username: aaaa, password: llkk, email: abc@gmail.com
updated user: username: aaaa, password: vvbb, email: abc@gmail.com
```

But nothing changes in `User` table!

Comment: The code looks fine, the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Email might not be matching hence no records are returned.

Comment: @DarshanLila See `UPDATE2`

Comment: It looks like your transaction is being rolled back.